# How to Implement a click-triggered div with slide from left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

This code works well on jsfiddle, but won't work in the browser, any ideas why?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/2184/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#clickme").click(function () {
        if ($("#slideout").hasClass("popped")) {
            $("#slideout").animate({
                left: '-280px'
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 500
            }).removeClass("popped");
        } else {
            $("#slideout").animate({
                left: "0px"
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 500
            }).addClass("popped");
        }
    });
});
</script>
<style>
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#slideout {
    background: #666;
    position: absolute;
    width: 280px;
    height: 80px;
    top: 45%;
    left: -280px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
#clickme {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 280px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #ff0000;
}
#slidecontent {
    float: left;
}
</style>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="slideout">
        Yar, there be dragonns herre!
    </div>

    <div id="clickme"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see jQuery included in your script?  Did you forget to include jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery needs to be included in order to use it.

You can do this either:

1. Downloading jQuery, and using from your computer
2. Use jQuery's CDN, and include if right from their website, http://code.jquery.com/

Then, include above your file script...  Like so:

```
<script src="path/or/url/to/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
/* Your other stuff */
</script>
```

---

If you were using jQuery's code right from their website.  This is an example using the 1.x

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
/* Your stuff here */
</script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, sorry, i'm a javascript noob.

Comment: That's alright, we all had to go through some basics at one point.